# android can't change imageview backround with runnable and thread method

Tags: android, multithreading, imageview

There is my MainActivity's code , I tried debug my code but no error.
    looking forward for you reply
    thank you

I 've already ommit some duplicated code!

```
package neusoft.duanxudong.com.myapplication;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ImageView img1;
    private TextView result;
    private Button startbutton;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        initView();
        startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {


                        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {


                            Random random = new Random();
                            int a = random.nextInt(7);




                            switch (a)

                            {
                                case 1:
                                    img1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    img1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    img1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    img1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    img1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                                    break;
                                case 6:
                                           img1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                                    break;
                                case 7:
                                    img1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);


                            }




                       }
                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(1000);

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }


                }.run();
            }
        });

    }




    public void initView() {
        img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


        startbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }

}
```

if you have any good method  to realize my idea  and you can reply
it always show""

Comment: What exactly is happening?

Comment: a/ never call  `Runnable.run`. it defeats the purpose of having a runnable. give it to a thread. b/ you sleep on the main thread. that's bad. that means nothing can happen in your ui

Comment: It happened just change the background color once.

Comment: Why are you using Runnable there? There is absolutely no need of that.

Comment: I want it can change background color 2o times and interval is 1second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView img1;
    private ImageView img2;
    private ImageView img3;
    private Button pausebutton;
    private TextView result;
    private Button startbutton;
    private Button stopButton;


    int color = Color.CYAN;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initView();

        startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {


                            Random random = new Random();
                            int a = random.nextInt(7);


                            switch (a)

                            {
                                case 1:

                                    color = Color.RED;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    color = Color.YELLOW;

                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    color = Color.WHITE;

                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    color = Color.BLACK;

                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    color = Color.BLUE;

                                    break;
                                case 6:
                                    color = Color.TRANSPARENT;

                                    break;
                                case 7:
                                    color = Color.GRAY;

                            }


                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    img1.setBackgroundColor(color);
                                }
                            });

                            if (i <= 20) {
                                try {

                                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                    e.printStackTrace();

                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
    }

    public void initView() {
        img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        startbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pausebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }
}
```

Comment: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: ok this is something wrong in your code because on my device works. Anyway, I edit the answer and added the whole MainActivity.java

Comment: if you keep facing the problem write the logcat here, so we can solve this

Comment: if that help you, you can accept my answer as correct :)

Comment: because my poor reputation ,It's occurs an error to votes you

Comment: No, I mean to press the check mark, so the other developers can see my answer if they have the same problem as you

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible answers:

Change:
   private ImageView img1;
    private ImageView img2;
     etc...
To:
   public ImageView img1;
    public ImageView img2;
    etc..

Or:

You can place the decelration of your imageview, buttons and textviews in the onCreate.

So like this:

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        startbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pausebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

etc..

I hope it helped.